# Perl substitute some content in a xml file

Tags: perl

I am a newbie of Perl. Now i am trying to use Perl to substitute some content in a xml file. the following code is my command

```
perl -pi -e "s/<Connector port=\"\d+\" protocol=\"HTTP/1.1\" /<Connector port=\"${ACCESS_PORT}\" protocol=\"HTTP/1.1\" /g" $TOMCAT_SERVER_CONF
```

but perl gives complains this:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near ""34233" protocol"
(Missing operator before protocol?)
Can't modify numeric lt (<) in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near ""34233" protocol"
syntax error at -e line 1, near ""34233" protocol"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

could anyone help out here? would be very appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the forward slash before the `1.1` in your command (there tare two same thing in your command in fact). Because you are using `/` as regex delimiter.

```
\"HTTP\/1.1\"
      ^ here
```

Alternately you can use any different regex delimiter as well. For example using a `hash`:

```
s#..regex..#;;replace;;#g
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex to parse XML. It's nasty. Use a parser instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig; 

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parsefile ( $ENV{'TOMCAT_SERVER_CONF'} ); 
foreach my $connector ( $twig -> get_xpath('Connector') ) {
    $connector -> set_att('port', $ENV{'ACCESS_PORT'} ); 
}
$twig -> print;
```

If you need an in place edit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub mod_connector {
    my ( $twig, $connector ) = @_;
    $connector->set_att( 'port', $ENV{'ACCESS_PORT'} );
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'Connector' => \&mod_connector } );
   $twig -> parsefile_inplace( $ENV{'TOMCAT_ACCESS_CONF'} );
```

And if you really want a one liner:

```
perl -MXML::Twig -e 'XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { Connector => sub { $_->set_att( "port", $ENV{ACCESS_PORT} ) }})->parsefile_inplace( $ENV{TOMCAT_ACCESS_CONF} );'
```